# Edited-and-Reopened Questions Should Ping Downvoters

Tags: feature-request, closing, down-votes, notifications

A somewhat common pattern on this site seems to be that a new user will post a poor question, receive a bunch of downvotes and have their question closed. If we're lucky, they'll (or someone) improve their question and it will be reopened. However, the initial downvotes will remain, many (if not most) of which may have been regarding presentation or context issues that were corrected in the edit, rather than the intrinsic value of the question. It is, unsurprisingly, also not too uncommon to see new users encountering this situation complain in the comments about how many downvotes their getting before they have a chance to improve their question - and, unfortunately, the best counsel to offer such users is to improve it anyways and hope that other people will upvote it afterwards.

To address this issue, I suggest the following:

> If a question is closed, edited, then reopened, anyone who cast a downvote on it should be pinged to look at the question again.

This feature would help to ensure that downvotes remain justified, even after the content to which they apply changes. However, given that it would only be triggered after an edit and 5 reopen votes cast by 3k+ users (presumably an edit which *causes* reopening), there would already be considerable evidence that the community has changed its opinion on the question before this feature would be activated. I doubt that this would become an annoyance, even to prolific downvoters, since reopening is not *too* common, and if such pings became excessive, one could constrain it to only apply to new questions or new users or significant edits. For new users, this feature could provide a "second chance", a greater incentive to edit their questions, and less frustration with quick downvotes. In short, it would be a relatively simple way to improve the experience of new users, without burdening much the rest of the community.

Comment: Request for someone skilled with Data.SE: Create a query that would show how often this would ping. (i.e. In the past week, how many questions were edited and reopened?)  If I got ~10 pings a day by this script, I'd probably be annoyed.

Comment: "(...) and if such pings became excessive, one could constrain it to only apply to new questions or new users or significant edits. " I think this is unnecessary, the question has been reopened, that should be a good enough filter.

Comment: For people who want to watch out for reopened questions: the dropdown in the lower right of [10k Moderator Tools](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last7days) for closevotes can be used to find these.

Comment: You are in good company: a similar request was made 5 years ago by Jon Skeet, and was declined:  [Allow an edit to notify downvoters: “I think I've fixed the issue now - please check”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751). However, yours is more specific in that it's about reopened questions only.

Comment: @anorton I wrote a query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/edit/259653) which *should* list all pings that'd occur last two weeks. It lists 204 pings (and should be an overestimate; voting times are rounded, but even just counting "downvotes on edited and reopened posts" is 215). In any case, that says 15 pings (sitewide) per day, which is not much at all. (It seems too low though - maybe my SQL's bad). Also, recall that, out of 40 votes/day, not very many will be downvotes on questions that will be editted and reopenned.

Comment: In some cases such pinging would speed up reclosure.